# Using C++ code in a PostgreSQL function or procedure

Tags: c++, postgresql

I have a compiled library on the same PC with **PostgreSQL** that I use with `#include <seal/seal.h>` when writing some **C++** code. I must use this library to work on some table values in my PostgresSQL database. Running a separate Client on the same PC with **Postgres** for the communication with the database is unfortunately not an option.

Is it possible to include and use the functions provided with `#include <seal/seal.h>` in a **PostgreSQL** function or a procedure? 
I read something about using:

```
external "C" {

#include <seal/seal.h>
// do something with the seal functions here

}
```

But there are not so many examples out there and I didn't understand it. The section about **C++** in the **PostgreSQL** documentation didn't make it clearer either.

Comment: To realize such you'll need to have a compiled module added to your PostgreSQL distribution IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation recommends, the functions that are called from PostgreSQL must be declared as `extern C` so that C code can link with them.

In the places where you have to call he functions from your C++ library, you use an exception handler that uses `catch (...)` to catch *all* possible exceptions and converts them into a PostgreSQL error message by calling `ereport()` (outside the `catch` clause, so that there is nothing C++ on your call stack).

If you have to call a PostgreSQL C function, make sure that the call stack does not contain any values that are not [plain old data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure):

> A PDS type in C++, or Plain Old C++ Object, is defined as either a scalar type or a PDS class. A PDS class has no user-defined copy assignment operator, no user-defined destructor, and no non-static data members that are not themselves PDS. Moreover, a PDS class must be an aggregate, meaning it has no user-declared constructors, no private nor protected non-static data, no virtual base classes and no virtual functions.

In short, write your code as C as possible, except where you call the library functions.

Comment: So lets see if I got you right. I start declaring a function or a procedure for my table in PostgerSQL and I write my C/C++ in `extern "C" { here }`. If so far was correct, then can the SQL variables outside `extern "C" { }` be used by variables inside `extern "C" { }`?

Comment: I don't follow... what is an "SQL variable"?

Comment: Poor choice of words. I meant any declared variable outside the `extern "C" { }` section but inside the PosgresSQL procedure or function.

Comment: Yes, certainly. As far as I know, `extern C` only influences how the linker names the symbol for the decorated function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to be working on it this Weekend, hopefully it works as planned :).